# WCF -Rest- DataContract : Deserialize XML wrapped response

Tags: c#, xml, rest, wcf, deserialization

Assuming we are using a REST WCF service returning xml.

Is it possible to deserialize "automatically" an xml wrapped response to a DataContract ?

**Simple example**

Class:

```
[DataContract]
public class TestClass
{
    [DataMember]
    string StringValue { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    int IntValue { get; set; }
}
```

Service:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "Test",
   BodyStyle      = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
   RequestFormat  = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
TestClass Test();
```

Client:

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    webClient.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/xml";
    webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    return webClient.DownloadString($"{BASE_URL}/Test");
}
```

Deserialization:

```
// With T as TestClass in or example.
public static T Deserialize<T>(string xml)
{
    using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        stream.Position = 0;
        DataContractSerializer deserializer =
             new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
        return (T)deserializer.ReadObject(stream);
    }
}
```

This code works well for bare response.

As webClient just return the full request, output xml contains thre wrapper element, and DataContractSerializer try parse a simple string, and don't now it come from WCF wrapped response (and should "forget" the wrapper).

Goal is to construct a client where wrapping style (bare/wrapped) doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just deserialize the output as a simple XML? something like this:

```
public static T XmlDeserializer<T>(string xmlString)
{
        var instance = default(T);
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (var stringreader = new StringReader(xmlString))
            instance = (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stringreader);

        return instance;
}
```

note: because of default `xmlns` tags you should use name space in your client side class like this:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfWebService")]
```

Comment: Sorry, but it is same problem with my main goal: work with wrapped and bare response.

Comment: dear @Manea. please post the whole response so i can help you. thanks.

Comment: Please look at **service** on my example: when it is set to BodyStyle      = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, the returning xml is "wrapped", and so deserialization doesn't work.  I m looking for a method to deserialize Xml generated by WCF , and this method should work for WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped  AND WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare.

Comment: dear @Manea. problem is not about serilization method. its about your output class. when you change the  BodyStyle.Wrapped your output changes. i have no idea how you consume the web service but if you can capture the output you will understand the problem.